# How to access the details of a logged in user

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

Our Society wishes to have some web pages outside Magento (1.9) but on the same web server and to control access to those pages according to the credentials of a person logged in to Magento.

Initially, we would like a page that is only visible to people logged in and belonging to a specific customer group.

Following on from that we would like to be able to control what features appear on a web page according to the person logged in.

On our previous non-e-commerce site the above was achieved by PHP pages that
1. used the logged-in details from phpBB
2. comparison of the logged-in person's id with authorities recorded in a MySQL database.

So I'm happy to write fairly simple things in PHP and SQL (procedural rather than object-oriented approach) but I have no knowledge of the inner workings of Magento.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
<?php
//Path to your Magento instance relative to your other page
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
umask(0); 

Mage::app(); Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

$customer_data = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->$session->id;

if($session->isLoggedIn()){ 

} else { 

} ?>
```

Comment: Many thanks - I'm sure I can work with this.